# How to see on which port apachi2 server is running

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, ubuntu-server

first i install apache2 using following command`sudo apt install apache2`.
I tried `sudo systemctl start apache2` to run server.
now i want to see on which port my server is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not searched a lot about your question, but here are some solutions:

`lsof -i` list open ports and the corresponding applications.

For a general check if an app is running you could just use `ps aux | grep apache2` or also `netstat -anp`.

There are [more solutions](https://serverfault.com/questions/131852/how-to-check-on-which-port-apache-is-running) over on Server Fault.